# Trim ID from metadata returned in a search display template

Tags: search, search-results, managed-metadata, display-template

I want to return metadata in the search results.  How can i trim the results and only show the term and not the ID?[image]

Comment: Maybe JavaScript ``split`` ?

Comment: Which Crawled Property did you pick? Usually there ate two choices and one has the IDs removed.

Comment: It's a custom property but it is mapped to another property.  I will try the mapped property....

Comment: OK. Bit of a newbie. Any suggestions :-)